# crontab not executing complex bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

---

SOLVED! add #!/bin/bash at the top of all my scripts in order to make use of bash extensions. Otherwise it restricts itself to POSIX shell syntax. Thanks Barmar!

Also, I'll add that I had trouble with gpg decryption not working from cronjob after I got it executing, and the answer was to add the --no-tty option (no terminal output) to the gpg command.

---

I am fairly new to linux, so bear with me...

I am able to execute a simple script with crontab -e when logged in as ubuntu:

```
* * * * * /ngage/extract/bin/echoer.sh
```

and this bash script simply prints output to a file:

```
echo "Hello" >> output.txt
```

But when I try to execute my more complex bash script in exactly the same way, it doesn't work:

```
* * * * * /ngage/extract/bin/superMasterExtract.sh
```

This script called into other bash scripts. There are 4 scripts in total, which 3 levels of hierarchy. It goes superMasterExtract > masterExtract > (decrypt, unzip)

Here is the code for superMasterExtract.sh (top level):

```
shopt -s nullglob      # ignore empty file
cd /str/ftp            
DIRECTORY='writeable'
for d in */ ; do         # for all directories in /str/ftp
if [ -d "$d$DIRECTORY" ]; then   # if the directory contains a folder called 'writeable'
files=($d$DIRECTORY/*)
dirs=($d$DIRECTORY/*/)
numdirs=${#dirs[@]}
numFiles=${#files[@]}
((numFiles-=$numdirs))
if [ $numFiles -gt 0 ]; then       # if the folder has at least one file in it
bash /ngage/extract/bin/masterExtract.sh /str/ftp ${d:0:${#d} - 1}   # execute this     masterExtract bash script with two parameters passed in
fi
fi
done
```

masterExtract.sh:

```
DATE="$(date +"%m-%d-%Y_%T")"
LOG_FILENAME="log$DATE"
LOG_FILEPATH="/ngage/extract/logs/$2/$LOG_FILENAME"
echo "Log file is $LOG_FILEPATH"
bash /ngage/extract/bin/decrypt.sh $1 $2 $DATE
java -jar /ngage/extract/bin/sftp.jar $1 $2
bash /ngage/extract/bin/unzip.sh $1 $2 $DATE
java -jar /ngage/extract/bin/sftp.jar $1 $2
echo "Log file is $LOG_FILEPATH"
```

decrypt.sh:

```
shopt -s nullglob
UPLOAD_FILEPATH="$1/$2/writeable"
DECRYPT_FOLDER="$1/decryptedFiles/$2"
HISTORY_FOLDER="$1/encryptHistory/$2"
DONE_FOLDER="$1/doneFiles/$2"
LOG_FILENAME="log$3"
LOG_FILEPATH="/ngage/extract/logs/$2/$LOG_FILENAME"
echo "DECRYPT_FOLDER=$DECRYPT_FOLDER" >> $LOG_FILEPATH
echo "HISTORY_FOLDER=$HISTORY_FOLDER" >> $LOG_FILEPATH
cd $UPLOAD_FILEPATH
for FILE in *.gpg;
do
    FILENAME=${FILE%.gpg}

    echo ".done FILE NAME=$UPLOAD_FILEPATH/$FILENAME.done" >> $LOG_FILEPATH

    if [[ -f $FILENAME.done ]]; then
        echo "DECRYPTING FILE=$UPLOAD_FILEPATH/$FILE INTO $DECRYPT_FOLDER/$FILENAME" >> $LOG_FILEPATH

        cat /ngage/extract/.sftpPasswd | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output "$DECRYPT_FOLDER/$FILENAME" --decrypt "$FILE"
        mv $FILE $HISTORY_FOLDER/$FILE

        echo "MOVING FILE=$UPLOAD_FILEPATH/$FILE INTO $HISTORY_FOLDER/$FILE" >> $LOG_FILEPATH
    else
        echo "Done file not found!" >> $LOG_FILEPATH
    fi 

done


cd $DECRYPT_FOLDER
for FILE in *
do
    mv $FILE $DONE_FOLDER/$FILE
    echo "DECRYPTED FILE=$DONE_FOLDER/$FILE" >> $LOG_FILEPATH
done
```

If anyone has a clue why it refuses to execute my more complicated script, I'd love to hear it. I have also tried setting some environment variables at the beginning of crontab as well:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=jgardnerx85@gmail.com
HOME=/
* * * * * /ngage/extract/bin/superMasterExtract.sh
```

Note, I don't know that these are the appropriate variables for my installation or my script. I just pulled them off other posts and tried it to no avail. If these aren't the correct environment variables, can someone tell me how I can deduce the right ones for my particular application?

Comment: Thanks for including the steps you've tried to debug this! [The crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) has some more, could you check those too?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

cron would, by default, emails the output of a job to the user owning the crontab.  However, email doesn't work "by default" on a *NIX box so emails just end up in the ether, not delivered.

I would:
1. add a "set -x" at the top of every script to show what's being executed, and
2. redirect each script's stdout and stderr output to files so you can inspect them: "scriptname=`basename $0`; exec >/tmp/$scriptname.stdout 2>/tmp/$scriptname.stderr"

Comment: These sound like useful debug tips. Thanks guys! So "set -x" at the top of a script outputs the filePath of the script? I don't understand "scriptname=basename" $0; but I think I understand the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to begin your script with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

in order to make use of `bash` extensions. Otherwise it restricts itself to POSIX shell syntax.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. For some reason that I'm having difficulty determining, the script is behaving differently when run as cron as opposed to running it in the terminal, but it is definitely running at least!

Comment: If a script doesn't begin with `#!`, it's executed by the current shell. Since you're using `bash` interactively, it gets all the extensions.